# convert angularjs to pure js or how to use single server for angular JS and Flask

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flask

As we know `angular` can build a project and convert to pure `HTML`, `CSS`, and `js` code. Similarly, I want my `AngularJS` application. When I run that app using `npm start` It works. I want to put that app in my backend as `index.html` as `template` so that no need for a separate front end server.

As shown below `backend` is a flask app and `frontend` is `angular JS` app.

Please suggest me the solution

1. How to convert code to pure Html CSS js? or
2. How to use angular JS frontend directly in flask backend as a template?

```sh
.
├── backend
│   ├── app.py
│   └── src
│       ├── db.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── run.py
│       └── secure.py
├── frontend
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.config.js
│   │   ├── app.css
│   │   ├── app.module.js
│   │   ├── home
|   |   |    ├── home.component.js
|   |   |    ├── home.component.spec.js
|   |   |    ├── home.module.js
|   |   |    └── home.template.html
│   │   ├── index.html
|   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── README.md
```

Comment: This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline. Please show your code. What doesn't work which snippet?

Comment: Everything Works but for starting application, we should start angularJS frontend and Flask backend. I want to put angularJS frontend in flask backend as one template.

Comment: No problem, but it is not related to StackOverflow, here you ask technical questions like I have an error or `this` method doesn't work. You asked the question related to architecture and design

Comment: It is not related to architecture or design at all. I found my solution. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I tried the whole day and finally found a solution accidentally in vs code live server extension. it is running there.

So what to do.

`index.html` is the starting point. So copy and paste it in the `templates` folder. (i am pasting inside the `app` folder which is in `templates`.

Next step, copy all other files and folders like `components`, app.config.js`,`app.css`,`app.module.js`etc to`static` folder.

Now change paths in `index.html` inside `templates` folder accordingly flask rules using `url_for`.

Changed code samples.

```html
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='lib/angular/angular.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='lib/angular-route/angular-route.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='app.module.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='app.config.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='home/home.module.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='home/home.component.js')}}"></script>
```

And also small changes to `component` which are in `static` folder

```js
templateUrl: '/static/home/home.template.html'
```

### Final folder structure

```sh
.
└── backend
    ├── app.py
    ├── src
    │   ├── db.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── run.py
    │   └── secure.py
    ├── static
    │   ├── app.config.js
    │   ├── app.css
    │   ├── app.module.js
    │   ├── home
    │   │   ├── home.component.js
    │   │   ├── home.component.spec.js
    │   │   ├── home.module.js
    │   │   └── home.template.html
    │   ├── img
    │   └── lib
    └── templates
        └── app
            ├── index-async.html
            └── index.html
```

Comment: Not sure what it is all about... In basic setup your app results in ~3 files: index.html, app.js and app.css (sometimes +libs.js, +libs.css, +images, +fonts, ...). This can be done with e.g. webpack... and this is same for Angularjs/Angular or prolly whatever other JS framework

Comment: `home` is a component I created every component inside a separate folder. `home` component has `template` and `component JS`. https://github.com/PSKP-95/code_rtc this is the my repo. If you want to check.

Comment: You seem not to use any build tool -- and nowadays you actually must or your life gets more complicated

Comment: Please you can suggest any build tool. I didn't found any.

Comment: e.g. webpack or grunt